# How to find the time postgresql was started via a query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to find the start time of a postgres DB, preferably via a query of some system_table (rather than parsing log files).
Is it possible?

Comment: One starts a server process with a DB-cluster, not a single DB.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT pg_postmaster_start_time();
```

Comment: [Link to manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html).